# How to print rows where value == string in list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                 words
1                 [me]
2               [they]
4         [it, we, it]
5                   []
6         [we, we, it]
```

I want to print rows where df.words == a certain word, like 'me', 'it', or no word. Normally, I would do something like this:

`df[df.words == 'me]` or `df[df.words == ''`, but when I do this, I get an empty data frame. What's going on here? How should I be treating the conditions I am searching on?

Comment: can you try : `df[pd.DataFrame(df['words'].tolist()).eq('me').any(axis=1)]` , since the series has lists , you can either iterate through the series and check with `df[['me' in i for i in df['words']]]` or you can convert to  dataframe and check like the previous method in my comment

Comment: try using isin()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to achieve the result.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(data=[["me"], ["they"], ["it", "we", "it"], [], ["we", "we", "it"]], name="words").to_frame()
filt = df["words"].apply(lambda x: "me" in x)
print(df.loc[filt])
```

For the case of an empty string

```
empty_filt = df["words"].apply(lambda x: len(x)==0)
print(df.loc[empty_filt])
```